# Is it DOS or DoS, and should we care?

Tags: discussion

Just thought I'd throw this out there for consideration.

DOS = Disk Operating System, and is an "acronym for several closely related operating systems that dominated the IBM PC compatible market between 1981 and 1995, or until about 2000 if one includes the partially DOS-based Microsoft Windows versions 95, 98, and Millennium Edition."  ([Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DOS))  The most prominent of these, of course, was MS-DOS

DoS = Denial of Service, which is a form of attack intended "to make a computer resource unavailable to its intended users."  ([Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack))

Since we do operate in an industry where both are commonly (though the former may be more rare these days) known and used acronyms, shouldn't we be ensuring that they are utilized appropriately?

Right now, I've only noticed one post that this particularly applies to.  But, I figured we should address it before there's more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Iszi - I have corrected that instance. I think you are right in principle but so far it doesn't look to be too big a deal, so we can always just change it as and when we see the wrong one used.

For people who don't have enough rep to edit, simple solution is to leave a message for a mod on chat, or leave a comment and someone else may edit it.

Comment: I agree that it's not that big a deal, there are few scenarios now (though they do exist) where anyone's using DOS to mean a CP/M rip-off.

Comment: I know, it was my post.  I was in a hurry, and didnt realize my error.  Thanks the catch.